# proper installation of node

Tags: node.js, homebrew

My understanding is that NVM is the preferred way to install and manage node versions over Homebrew. 
I have a couple versions of Node installed with NVM. But it looks like the Homebrew installation is still there too.  I tried `brew uninstall` node but got an error

```
Error: Refusing to uninstall /usr/local/Cellar/node/8.0.0_1
because it is required by babel 6.24.1, yarn 0.24.6, which are 
currently installed.
You can override this and force removal with:
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two packages installed by Homebrew (babel and yarn) that depends on node. You have two choices:

1) You don't need babel and yarn anymore. You can remove them with:

```
brew uninstall babel
brew uninstall yarn
```

and then you will be able to remove the node version installed by Homebrew:

```
brew uninstall node
```

2) You want to keep babel and yarn. Both of these packages depend on node. If you install a node version with nvm, they will rely on this new version. So you can uninstall the homebrew version with:

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node
```

Comment: Yup. So correction, those were warnings about dependencies... not errors. I proceeded to do the brew uninstall... No problems.